# Extract first 3 words from string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split, python-2.x

I am looking for a script code to search for the first 3 words of a string.

Example :

```
words = 'I am confused looking for 3 words from the front'
```

Expected results:

```
'I am confused'
```

Comment: What are you asking about? It isn't appropriate to ask for code here. What have you already tried?

Comment: _Your confusion is clear but maybe you can prevent **ours**_. What is the criterion; which 3 words? Any?

Comment: Are you "searching", or only want to split the string on the third space?

Comment: You took a wild guess there @cricket_007.

Comment: @Ev it does say "for 3 words from the front"

Comment: @cricket_007 I didn't see that, sorry. That's a new _meta_. Hiding the request in a code string. Genius.

Comment: @all Sorry for my litle description

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 for editing title

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can split the string into a list using the .`split()` method. Once you've done this you can extract the first 3 words from the sentence using a list slice (`[:3]`). Finally you'll want to join the result back together into a new string using `.join()`:

```
words = 'I am confused looking for 3 words from the front'
' '.join(words.split()[:3])
>> 'I am confused'
```